# Can't add image on Cordova 2.0

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a project on Cordova 2.0 and I don't know why but I can only use 1 image, the one in the `hello world` when you create a new project.

I'm using `Visual studio 2010` with `wp7 sdk` and cordova 2.0 sdk.

**Here an example of a simple code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width;" />

        <title>Hello Cordova</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="example">
                <p class="hi">Hi guys !!</p>
                <p class="image"> This is the cordova image:
                    <img src= ./img/cordova.png />
                </p>
                <br />
                <p class="cat"> And this is a cat:
                    <img src= ./img/cat.png />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I start my apps on wp7:

[image: wp7screen]

As you can see there is no cat...

My `cat.png` (64ko 170x200px) and `cordova.png` (20ko, 170x200px) are in the same folder of course.

The funniest part is that, in visual studio, you can see the design, and I can see my image:

[image: visual studio design]

I have no idea why the `wp7` emulator doesn't want to display my image.

I tried to refresh it (because when I changed my `applicationIcon`, I needed to refresh it to see my new image) but nothing happened...

If someone has any idea / solution?

P.S: sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To fix this error follow these steps**

1. From Soulion Explorer, right click the image and click Properties
2. Select "**Build Action**", then select "**Content**"
3. Save and Run
4. Done

Comment: what about if you are not using an IDE with a solution explorer, and you are using grunt? @PalaniKumar

Answer (score 1):

Depends where is the folder with images and html page.

< img src="../img/cat.png" >

Comment: The path is good because he can find my cordova image.
[path](http://hpics.li/147999f)